# Strange distortion of web pages

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, browser, amd-radeon

This appears sometimes, usually when the page is opened for a while (I'm using Google Chrome):

[image: screenshot]

The page should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

My system:

- Asus P8Z77-V LK
- Aero Cool KCAS 400W Bronze 80+
- Intel Core i5-3570K @ 4Ghz
- XFX RX 580 8Gb
- Kingston 8 + Corsair 4Gb RAM @ 1600MHz
- SSD 120Gb + HD WD Blue 1Tb

Can someone say what the problem is? Is my graphics card dying?
It's fine when I play games.

Btw, the graphics card is not overclocked, I even lowered the frequencies, but it was earlier overclocked. And I used it for mining for a half of year(temperature was in boundaries of 75)

**UPD:** It turned out that the problem really was in the graphics card(most likely the **VRAM**)

Comment: Yeah, that’s really weird that it would suddenly switch to Russian / Cyrillic.  What?  That’s not the problem you’re talking about?  Then tell us what the problem is — and/or add an image of what you want / expect the page to look like. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.